# Выборка данных из дб контекста (Не удалось вычислить выражение)

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Сильно не пинать, только учусь.

Есть скуль экспресс, есть дб, есть контекст дб, есть таблица тикетов и прочие таблицы. Во всех таблицах есть данные (выбираются селектом из менеджер студии). Но вот в момент выбора данных из контекста в вижуал студии возникают проблемы с таблицей тикетов: итемы выбираются, но у каждого нет данных и в значении стоит "Не удалось вычислить данные".

https://gyazo.com/630a59178eec1941f84dfdddb04405ea

На скрине видно что в таблице ордерс данные есть и выбираются нормально, но из тикетс выбирается 14 неопределенных элементов. проверял модель тикетов, проверял соединения - все в порядке.

**Собственно вопрос**: что не так с выборкой данных, и в какую сторону копать, чтобы решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все просто, необходимо установить нужную опцию в настройках дебагера. Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"

[image: настройки]